# php upload black bg on transparent gifs and png's

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am using a jquery / php plugin to upload and crop images. It all works fine except for the black background on transparent gifs/pngs. I want to keep the transparency. I have read through other posts and realise this has come up before but dont fully understand how to apply previous fixes to my code.

```
            <?php
            ##########################################################################################################
            # IMAGE FUNCTIONS                                                                                        #
            # You do not need to alter these functions                                                               #
            ##########################################################################################################
            function resizeImage($image,$width,$height,$scale) {
                list($imagewidth, $imageheight, $imageType) = getimagesize($image);
                $imageType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);
                $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
                $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
                $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
                switch($imageType) {
                    case "image/gif":
                        $source=imagecreatefromgif($image); 
                        break;
                    case "image/pjpeg":
                    case "image/jpeg":
                    case "image/jpg":
                        $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($image); 
                        break;
                    case "image/png":
                    case "image/x-png":
                        $source=imagecreatefrompng($image); 
                        break;
                }
                imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);

                switch($imageType) {
                    case "image/gif":
                        imagegif($newImage,$image); 
                        break;
                    case "image/pjpeg":
                    case "image/jpeg":
                    case "image/jpg":
                        imagejpeg($newImage,$image,90); 
                        break;
                    case "image/png":
                    case "image/x-png":
                        imagepng($newImage,$image);  
                        break;
                }

                chmod($image, 0777);
                return $image;
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: If you'd properly ready previous answers, you'd realize you need to turn on alpha preservation in GD: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php  http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php

Answer (score 2):

I made progress by adding

```
            imagealphablending($newImage, true); 
            // Allocate a transparent color and fill the new image with it. 
            // Without this the image will have a black background instead of being transparent.
            $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha( $newImage, 0, 0, 0, 127 ); 
            imagefill( $newImage, 0, 0, $transparent ); 
                imagesavealpha($newImage,true);
```

below the line $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);

it works for pngs now but not gifs???